# php script error debug

Tags: php, debugging

I have a problem a simple php coding error and I cannot find out where is exactly the error, is there a way how to debug php script ?

```
<?php  
    $fnC = "./includes/dbConnect.php" ;   
    if(file_exists($fnC) )  {
      require_once($fnC); 
      echo "$fnC is found" ; 
    }  
    else
    { 
        echo "file does not exist : $fnC" ;  
    } 
?>
<?php  
    $fnF = "./includes/dbFunctions.php" ; 
    if(file_exists($fnF) )  {
      require_once($fnF); 
      echo "$fnF is found" ;
    }  
    else {
        echo "file does not exist : $fnF" ;  
    } 
?>

<?php
    foreach($_POST as $key => $i){
            print("$key=$i<br>");
    }


echo "script finish";
?>
```

Any clue where is the error ?
the 2 files  exists inside includes/, got the first echo of dbConnect.php (file exists) then nothing 
, script stops
Thanks.

Comment: Check the `error_log`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to check error in php you use php error reporting:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

you put that code at the top of your php code.

this will print out any error(s) that you have in your php code.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer, i m going to test now

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, you need to maintain the order of includes!
When your file being included needs some resources (like class definition, function body, etc), the file that has those resources should be included first.

However, this is not necessary if you write whole things within a single file.

If you get "**failed to open stream**" although you are sure your *include_path* is correct, check your `open_basedir` setting. So to avoid any strange problems and painfull debugging make sure ALL paths you use within the system have the same case everywhere, and that they correspond with the actual case of the filesystem. That includes include paths set in webserver `config/php.ini`, auto load config, runtime include path settings or anywhere else.

This can be simply because your included directory is outside the scope of the `open_basedir` which blocks php from accessing file outside you root directory(usually).